# HP Fortify Build Monitor

Tags: c++, command-line, fortify

i am trying to scan c++ code in SCA using command line tool. To convert build into pfr file the guide is asking me to use **"HP Fortify Build Monitor"**. But I cant seem to find this tool in installed applications in SCA. I have googled it also but there seems to be no support.

Answer (score 0):

HP Fortify Build Monitor supports for version 4.20 and below only. 

For C++ projects and solutions on Windows, SCA includes the HP Fortify Build Monitor, which is a graphical user interface tool that automates analysis during builds.
To analyze C/C++ source code builds on Windows:
1. Select Start > Program Files > HP Fortify Software > HP Fortify v3.80 > HP Fortify SCA ‐ Build Monitor.
2. Click Monitor.
After the monitor initiates a green light icon displays.
3. Create a complete build of your project in your build environment.
4. Check that the build has finished successfully.
5. Return to the HP Fortify Build Monitor window and click Build Done.
6. SCA outputs the results to a subfolder, specify a name for the folder for the output. If the folder already exists, SCA cleans the folder before starting the scan.
7. Click Scan.

Comment: To make everyone aware, the Build Monitor is only available on the 32-bit Windows version of Fortify and only supported for version 4.10 and earlier.